# Would the initialization value be computed at compile time or runtime?

Tags: c++, runtime, compile-time, variable-initialization

if i have a function that uses the `rand()` function as its initialization value, would that value be found when the program compiles, or when the function is run?

say:

```
int function(int init = rand()){
  return init;
}
```

if it is found at compile time, how can i get the initialization to be dynamic? i guess i would use `NULL` as the initialization value, but how would i tell the difference between `NULL` and `init = 0`?

Answer (score 6):

The value is calculated in runtime.

You can always create a tiny program and check that on practice:

```
int main() {
    srand( time(NULL) );
    std::cout << function() << std::endl;
}
```